# android studio SDK installment issues

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

android studio SDK installment issues - I cant download the SDK through the android studio.

I tried downloading the SDK after installing android studio and it does not let me install it in the normal directory path (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk) because my username is in my language (non ASCII). I can't change my user folder name, and puting a different directory path (C:\Program Files (x86)\AndroidStudioSDK for example) also does not work - it automatically unchecks all the SDK downloading boxes and im not able to recheck them. Help?
[The SDK downloading page with the normal directory path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbsGe.png)
[The SDK downloading page when given a different directory path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCpi6.png)

Comment: Creating a user account with non-ASCII characters is an easy way to find all the bugs in Windows and other software - so it is only a good idea if you love trouble.

Comment: I know, it's not my computer... and I can't edit the file name...